# The limit as a function on functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

Is the observation that, "*The limit is a function on functions*," true or meaningful? Since the limit is unique, if it exists, then the pair
$\displaystyle(c,\lim_{x\to c}f(x))$ itself defines a function for some function $f$. I was just thinking about the idea and wanted some outside feedback.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing this, but I'm also probably wrong. If $x \in (a,b)$ and we try to make a function $\lim_{x\to c}: (\text{any function having all its 2 sided limits in } (a,b)) \to \mathbb{R}$. The problem is that you can't define this domain without defining the limit function first. And you can't define a function without first defining a domain. So we get into a circle of problems? As an aside, $(c, \lim_{x\to c}$ difference quotient $f$) is a very common graph

Comment: By using the set of all subsequence limits at a point the "limit operation" gives rise to a set-valued map from the reals to the collection of nonempty closed subsets of the reals. See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11228-005-5135-y) for one of many that take this viewpoint.

Answer (score 8):

This is true (in a sense) but probably not often useful. If $f$ is continuous the function whose graph is $(c, \lim_{x \to c} f(x))$ is just $f$.

There is, however, a related idea that's very important. If you have a set of functions with the same domain and codomain then for each $c$ you can consider the *evaluation map* whose graph is the set
$$
(f, f(c)) .
$$
That function of functions has many uses and far reaching generalizations.