# Limit as a Function on Sequence Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

The question is motivated by the following posts: [A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365801/viewing-limit-as-a-map) and [B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913483/the-limit-as-a-function-on-functions).  Let $X$ be a metric space (probably only Hausdorff is needed but I'm being safe) and let $X_0$ be the subspace of the sequence space $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ (equipped with the product topology) whose elements $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfy $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n \in X$.

Let $\operatorname{Lim}$ denote the map from $X_0$ to $X$ taking a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to $X$.  When is this function continuous, is this object studied (in this setup), and if so what are some references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in rather nice cases the map $\operatorname{Lim}$ need not be continuous. Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ define a sequence $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ as follows:

$$x_k^{(n)}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }k\le n\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly each of these sequences converges to $0$. However, the sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, the sequence that is constant at $1$.

Comment: But can we equip $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ with a Hausdorff topology for which $\operatorname{Lim}$ is continuous?  (Obviously taking the weak topology works but its not clear if that one is Hausdorff)...

Comment: @James_T: $X$, or $X^{\Bbb N}$?

Comment: Sorry, $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ since otherwise its clear that any such topology on $X$ would not be Hausdorff.  (Note that I allow for different topologies for X in the domain, i.e.: when considering $X^{\mathbb{N}}$, and on $X$ in the codomain)

Comment: @James_T: I’ll give it some thought, but nothing occurs to me immediately.

Comment: I was thinking about it, I think if $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is equipped with the sup-metric $d((x_n),(y_n)):= \sup_n d(x_n,y_n)$ (and we consider the appropriate subspace of $X_0$ of sequences with finite distance to some distinguised point) then your counter-example won't work anymore.  (Unless I'm missing something...)

Comment: @James_T: Yes, in that case the sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ doesn’t converge at all.